# align the icon with the p tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a chunk of code like below

```
<p class= "p_class" id="txtUserStatus">Add a description about your self.. </p>

<i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true" id="btnEditStatus"></i>
<input type="text" id="place_id" rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" form="usrform" style ="display:none;">
<span class="fa-stack fa-1x" id = "okID" style = "display:none;">
<i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i>
<i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span>
```

I want to align/place the pencil icon just after the `p` tag which I am unable to do.

On click of the `p`, you see a textbox and ok icon, so by default the pencil icon should be at the position of the ok icon.

Can someone help me do this simple CSS fix.

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8sf3ztor/2/).

NOTE : Don't want my icon class inside `p` tag.

Comment: Why do you need CSS? Just put the `i` inside the `p`: https://jsfiddle.net/8sf3ztor/3/

Comment: just added a note, I don't want to do that.

Comment: This will cause the icon when clicking on the label to move to the top. The behaviour of your first solution was better as the pencil icon would be invisible when editing the text.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8sf3ztor/6/ Is like that you want !!

Answer (score 4):

Just provide `display: inline-block` to your `.p_class` class.

This will let your `.p_class` div not to occupy the entire width of the container, and your `.fa-pencil` icon which is `display: inline-block` by default will occupy space after `.p_class`.

```
.p_class {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want the icon floating after you tag
CSS:

```
i {float:left}
```

Comment: don't think that will work when the p-tag has a width of 73%. I guess the pencil icon should be next to the contained text, not to the p-tag.

Answer (score 0):

add the following to the css:

```
.p_class{
  display:inline-block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like: 
`.p_class {
  float: left;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can add display:inline-block to class "p_class"

Answer (score 0):

just add following class

```
#txtUserStatus{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your icon after the `<p>` do:

```
p::after {
    content:url(youricon.png);
    <related CSS here>
}
```